# Is it possible to prevent a Ruby instance from opening network connection?

Tags: ruby, testing

I maintain a web API written in Ruby. It connects to many third party web services. When writing tests, I stub any function that would need to connect to the network and return bottled data instead.

It has happened to me before that I forget this stubbing step, and my integration tests end up actually connecting to a third party service.

With that in mind, I would like to prevent Ruby from being able to open network connections. When attempted, I would like it to raise an exception instead, pointing out what function I forgot to stub.

Is this possible? What central Ruby function would I need to override to achieve this with minimal other side effects?

Answer (score 1):

What about WebMock? Did you try it? https://github.com/bblimke/webmock

This line should help:

```
WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)
```

Comment: Alas, this only appears to disable HTTP connections... Libraries like [ruby-ldap](https://github.com/ruby-ldap/ruby-net-ldap) are still allowed to connect using TCP connections.

Answer (score 1):

Manual stubbing is, as you've just said, unreliable.

A better solution might be to wrap your code that calls external services behind a facade, and use dependency injection to pass the web handling service into the facade on creation.  Your Test Suite then just needs to do the same with a stub service.  You'd only need to do this once, and any test which was then testing external code would use the stubbed service.

Comment: Good advice in general, I guess, but it doesn't help me much right now. I don't want to refactor my whole code base, I just want to make sure Ruby can't open any network sockets when running unit tests.

Comment: If it'd take refactoring your whole code base then there's a basic problem with the code base and it probably needs refactoring. Your use of HTTP should be bottlenecked into a single method where it'd be easy to mock/redirect/subvert.

Comment: @theTinMan As I said, it's just HTTP I'm talking about, I'm talking about all connections to the network including basic TCP/UDP connections.

Comment: @theTinMan That was supposed to be "it's **not** just HTTP I'm talking about"

Answer (score 0):

Check out [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr).

First, take a look at [its documentation](https://relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/docs) and see if it's what you need, which I suppose it is. We've been using it at my company for a few years to record one HTTP test for a spec and replay the results for subsequent tests.

We've found it to be invaluable when dealing with external APIs.